# Strange padding around text making containing div too large

Tags: css, html, text, padding

I have been researching and working so hard to fix such a strange problem. I have a div that is supposed to hold some text. This div should be able to resize with that text, so that if there are two lines of text the div gets taller, etc. All that seems to work fine, but for some reason there's some sort of padding added to the top of the text and to the bottom of the text. I can't find what is causing that padding, and I really want to make the div fit the text more compactly. Here is an image of what i'm talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/01tDY.png

The light blue box should be shorter in height so it fits the text more closely. Here is my CSS code for this div:

```
.captionCSS {
    max-width:70%;
    margin-top:10px; 
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    padding-left:5px; 
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-top:0px; 
    padding-bottom:0; 
    background-color:#aef7f8; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    color:black; 
}
```

I have messed around with all of the margins and paddings, setting them to zero and then setting them back again and nothing seems to work. The line height is inherited from another div and is 18px, while the font size is 12px, and i tried decreasing the line height but it didn't have any effect on the top and bottom padding/gap.

Also, when the text takes up two lines, it get a bit worse in that there is an extra bit of padding on the side, which i want to get rid of:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cta9p.png

So yeah, that's my issue. Ideally I would like a 5px gap from the edge of the div to the top of the text, so if there is anyway to do that please let me know! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I think your issue is the margin you have set. The CSS is not applied to the boxt but the  `p` tags in the box. I'm sure if you displayed an example of all your CSS and HTML this would be confirmed.

Comment: Have you checked the line-height property?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the following.

If your code looks similar to this:

```
<p>Some text with <span class="captionCSS">highlighted text</span>.</p>
```

apply the following CSS rules:

```
p {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 5px;
}
.captionCSS {
    max-width:70%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    background-color:#aef7f8; 
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.00;
}
```

If you set `display: inline-block` to the caption wrapper, then the line height value will have some effect.

`line-height: 1.00` forces the line height to be the same size as the font-size for the element.  If you set the value to be less than 1, you will get a tighter fit but you may also clip ascenders and descenders of certain characters depending on the font.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2cyaF/

Answer (score 0):

Without the HTML I can't be sure, but my first guess is that the text has a parent block level element that already has styling rules. (ex: `<hX>` or `<p>`)

You can clear those styles through css by doing something like this:

```
h1,h2,h3,p{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Here are some example cases using your style: http://jsfiddle.net/JTrWL/